# How to return multiple integers from a method of type int

Tags: java, arrays, return-value, mode

As the title states, I'm attempting to return multiple integers from a method of type int (`int mode(int [] a`) . The method is designed to take in an array of integers and determine what the mode(s) would be. Another catch is that each value in the index of `int [] a` will range from 1-3. I cannot create objects, other methods to handle part of the solution or import anything to help me.

The problem I'm running into is if there are multiple modes in the array

ie. `int [] array = {1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6}`

As you can see, there's two modes in this case which are 2 and 3 and I'm not able to figure out how to return multiple integers from one method.

**HERE ARE MY PROFESSORS INSTRUCTIONS"**

"Write the method int mode(int []a). This function takes an array a indexed     from 1 to a.length. Each cell of a contains either 1,2, or 3. Your function   returns the value (1,2,3) that occurs most frequently in array a. You are expected to not use any imports(ie. Math, arraylists, etc) or change the return type. Assume that  main only contains an array, and then a call to the mode method using the aforementioned array in main. Here is the template: "

int mode(int [] a){

}

Here's what my code looks like:

```
public static int mode(int [] a){

int value = 0;
int countOne= 0;
int countTwo = 0;
int countThr = 0;

for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++){
    int count = 0;
    for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
        if(a[i] == a[j]){
            if(a[i] == 1){
                countOne++;
            }
            if(a[i] == 2){
                countTwo++;
            }   
            if(a[i] == 3){
                countThr++;
            }
        }

    }
}
   if(countOne > countTwo && countOne > countThr)
       value = countOne;
   if(countTwo > countOne && countTwo > countThr){
       value = countTwo;
   }
   if(countThr > countOne && countThr > countTwo){
       value = countThr;
   }
   /* if(countThr == countTwo){
          return countThr, countTwo;
   if(countOne == countTwo){
          //return countOne, countTwo;
   if(countOne == countThree){
          return countOne, countThree;
      */       

   return value;
```

`

`main{
int [] a = {1,2,2,3,3};
System.out.println(modeTwo(a));`

`Output:
 3`

While three is partially correct, since there a multiple modes in this case my desired output is

`Desired Output:
 2  3`

In the mode method I'm just creating a counter for 1-3 to see how many times each occurs in the array. Then I set up conditionals to check which is greatest. I attempted to create conditions to check if they were equal as well, however it wouldn't work since I'd have to return two integers. I'm just completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

int mode(int [] a){

}

Comment: The return type should be something like `Set<Integer>` or `int[]`. It should not be `int`.

Comment: Just create an array of integers, find the max occurrences and add the values which have a max occurrence and return it. In main you'll then iterate in that array and print the elements.

Comment: @ pbabcdefp i don't have a choice as this was what my professor specified to be the return type.

Comment: Well then either your professor has a fundamental misunderstanding of Java's return types, or you have a fundamental misunderstanding about your assignment

Comment: You could return `23` and separate the digits, but that seems hacky. Are you sure you understood the professor's question correctly?

Comment: @rze if single int mandated as the method interface - I assume  your professor wants you to return best or any matching result. There are hacky ways to pack several small numbers into single int, but it should not be your case

Comment: can you post the assessment ???

Comment: In theory you could also do something with a bit mask maybe. Depends on the exact details, though.

Comment: @fge, passive aggressive, nice.
 But to StrongJoshu, harshtuna , Fakher, Marvin I've added the exact instructions from the assignment

Comment: well, no sane professor would teach newbie to play with bitmasks

Comment: Are you sure that the program will ever be tested with an array that has two (or more) modes?

Comment: @StrongJoshua, it was never stated to watch out for multiple modes. However I'm assuming it needs to be taken into consideration. I know there is a good chance that  my assumption is over complicating this but I wanted to check stack overflow prior to just turning it as is.

Comment: Depending the level of the Java class this could be part of the assignment, but since it seems you are in a beginner, or close, class, I think you are just over complicating the assignment.

Comment: Your professor, in all likelihood, devised this assignment as an exercise in arithmetic operators.

Comment: From the instructions I would assume that there should always be *one* number which occurs most frequently. However, to be on the safe side, I would add a comment to the method and specify the behavior in case there are multiple numbers. Something like "if two or more numbers have the same occurrence, then the largest/smallest/random/first by index/last by index one is returned". Or whatever you think fits best. Your professor can't blame you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Given your update about not being able to use ArrayLists or import other libraries, I made a custom class for counting occurrences `Modes` and am using just arrays to still count the max occurrences of each number, but only return the numbers in an `int[]` whose occurrences equal the max occurrences.

Here's what I could come up with that will count all occurrences of each number in the array and return each number that has the max occurrences, which is the same as the mode.

```
   public static void main(String eth[]) {
        int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 10, 12, 33};
        int[] modes = mode(numbers);

        for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) {
            if (modes[i] == -999) { // Stop printing once you reach the first sentinal value
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(modes[i]);
        }
    }

    private static int[] mode(int[] numbers) {
        Modes[] modes = new Modes[numbers.length];
        int modesIndex = 0;

        int maxOccurrence = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] == -999) {
                continue;
            }

            int number = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = -999; // -999 is a sentinel value

            int count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] == -999) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (numbers[j] == number) {
                    numbers[j] = -999;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > maxOccurrence) {
                maxOccurrence = count;
            }
            modes[modesIndex++] = new Modes(number, count);
        }

        int[] result = new int[numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = -999; // Sentinel value
        }

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) {
            if (modes[i] == null) {
                break; // Stop when you hit the first null
            }
            if (modes[i].Occurrences == maxOccurrence) {
                result[index] = modes[i].Number;
                index++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static class Modes {
        public int Number;
        public int Occurrences;

        public Modes(int number, int occurrences) {
            Number = number;
            Occurrences = occurrences;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So what you need to do here is to do divide and mod operations to extract individual digits in your return.

For example:

"Desired Output:
 2  3"

Your method will return 23. To extract anything in the "ones" column, do num % 10. To extract the 2, divide the number by 10: num / 10 = secondDigit. If you have a three digit number, divide it by 100.

This is how you extract the numbers. I will leave it up to you to construct the 3 digit return value.

Comment: This may work, **but** if this is really the intention of the professor, the somewhere something went horribly wrong.

Comment: I don't really see why it wouldn't be. I personally have had two different intro classes where it was an exercise to extract individual digits in a number. rze has to be in some kind of intro class for this to be the constraints on the assignment. Remember that academic problems may not always map to the real world.

Comment: Sure, this task on its own (extracting digits from an `int`, or assembling an `int` from digits (without string concatenation)) is perfectly valid and important. But from the description of the task, I'm pretty sure that there is a misunderstanding: If there are multiple "most frequent" elements, then it should simply return *one* of them. Otherwise, the method signature simply would not make sense.

Comment: nvm, I see why some people have an issue with it. Idk I just look at it as that is just how the assignment is